# Multiple datasources for one model in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I have a very interesting problem in relation to CakePHP.  I have a client that is currently selling products on eBay, and wants to start selling products on their own website as well.  There would, then, be two separate sales avenues: (1) eBay, and (2) website.

However, they do want to have a seamless website experience for their customers.  Basically, they want their current eBay sites to be categories within their current website, and their current eBay auction items to be searchable on their website.

A simple CakePHP website would have two tables: products and categories, with the simple table relation of "products belongsTo categories" and "categories hasMany products".  How would I then add in the eBay categories and products?  Basically, I want the http://site/products/index to return a list of ALL products, both in the products table and on eBay.  I want http://site/categories/index to return a list of all defined categories in the categories table plus the categories items are listed in on eBay.

eBay has a very good pretty much real-time request query API, so I've been thinking about an option to do this, but am wondering if there is a better way...  I don't think this option would work very well with PaginatorComponent...

Method:
(1) In beforeFind, capture the request parameters and save to a persistent variable
(2) In afterFind, make a request to the eBay API based on the request parameters, then manually add the results to the $results array.

Again, I think this would work for basic find operations, but I'm not sure this would work with pagination because I'm not sure how to deal with, say, a 20 item page limit (i.e. How do I deal with a page 2 when only 18 items from the database were on page 1, and now on page 2 I need to start at 19 instead of 21 from the database?)

Is there a CakePHP syntax that I'm overlooking here, or do I just start working on coding for all of these eventualities?

I'm coding on a CakePHP 2.6.0 platform.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Why not import data from e-bay in your database ? I have one application that work with six datasources (beatport, soundcloud, twitter, facebook, GA, youtube). Background application periodically check if any change on remote sources and update local database. If user add data through cms, app update remote source.

Comment: The biggest problem with that is:  eBay product information changes very quickly (especially price, which can change on a second-to-second basis at the end of auctions).

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to read all the products from each datasource, sort them in memory and paginate from there. The number of products would of course play a major role here.

A second one, if the number of products does not change too often, would involve a background process to retrieve their ID, and the most essential data, from eBay and write them in the common Product table, flagging the rows created.
Then Paginator can then show your results, but other fast-changing data can be retrieved on-the-fly from eBay for the flagged products while composing the page.

Comment: So, right now with the small size of the store and the small amount of traffic, I decided to implement the first approach.  It works pretty well, I overloaded the find() function in the model.

I basically read the $options['limit'], $options['maxLimit'], and $options['page'] into local variables, unset them, run parent::find('all', $options).  Then I manually insert the eBay items, run an array_multisort() on each of the $options['order'], then array_slice based on the limits and paging information.

Comment: It's inefficient, but at this scale I'm not overly concerned.  If scale grows, I'll have to write data to the table and implement eBay's push API.